# Changing source through JQuery in html5 video not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

**Issue:** changing source element of HTML5 video through jQuery throws error in IE9

This is my jQuery function to change the video source:

```
var hdswipe = function(){
                var currVid, currExt, currVidName, currQuality, i, tempExt;
                if($hdVideo.attr('paused')==false)
                    playerstage=1;
                currVid = $hdVideo[0].currentSrc;
                currExt = currVid.substr(currVid.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

                for(i=0; i<videoAttr.quality.length; i++) //Get current video quality
                    if(currVid == videoAttr.src[i])
                        currQuality=videoAttr.quality[i];

                for(i=0; i<videoAttr.quality.length; i++) //Swipe the Video
                {
                    tempExt = videoAttr.src[i].substr(videoAttr.src[i].lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                    if((currExt==tempExt)&&(currQuality!= videoAttr.quality[i]))
                    {
                        $hdVideo.attr('src', videoAttr.src[i]);
                        createSeek();
                        createBuffer();
                        playerstage=0;
                        gPlay();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(currQuality == "sd")
                    $("a.hd-hd-swipe-button").addClass("hd-hd-swipe-button-hd");
                else
                    $("a.hd-hd-swipe-button").removeClass("hd-hd-swipe-button-hd");
               return false;
            }
```

Error message shows up in IE9, when this line get executed:

```
$hdVideo.attr('src', videoAttr.src[i]);
```

The error message is:

> Undefined Function in: $hdVideo.attr('buffered').end(0);

But the buffering function works fine since I play the video till the "hdswipe" function get called.

Please solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should try using this syntax:

```
$hdVideo[0].buffered.end(0);
```

Comment: Hey @Armel Larcier,
Again it shows the same error.
Do u have any other ideas in this issue?